# Differentiate functions

Tags: calculus

I have been learning differentiation, the power rule and chain rule.

Which rule would apply to this:

$$y = 4\cos(5x) - 3\sin (2x)$$

Can anyone help?

I am trying to work this out but do not know how.

Thanks,

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}cos(f(x)) = -f^\prime(x)sin(f(x))$ where $f(x)$ in this case is just $x$. This does not involve any sort of power differentiation.

Comment: Please use Mathjax here.  The power rule is for powers.  The chain rule is for composition of functions.  Which do you have here?

Comment: Tried helping by clarifying what is inside the cos and sins with parens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you will need the chain rule and the fact that
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)+g(x))=f'(x)+g'(x)$$
You also need to know that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\cos x=-\sin x$$
Using this, you can say that
$$\frac{d}{dx}(4\cos 5x-3\sin 2x)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}(4\cos 5x)+\frac{d}{dx}(-3\sin 2x)$$
$$=4\frac{d}{dx}(\cos 5x)-3\frac{d}{dx}(\sin 2x)$$
Then use the chain rule:
$$=4(-5\sin 5x)-3(2\cos 2x)$$
$$=-20\sin 5x-6\cos 2x$$

And that should be it! If any of this is unclear, please let me know and I will be happy to explain further!

Comment: You have explained it perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(a \sin b x) &= ab \cos b x \\
 \frac{d}{dx}(\alpha \cos \beta x) &= -\alpha \beta \sin \beta x\, \qquad (a, b, \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R})
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use the chain rule $$(g\circ f)'(x)=g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x).$$ Thus

$$\dfrac{d \sin (ax)}{dx}\underbrace{=}_{f=\sin x,g=ax}=a\cos(ax).$$

Answer (score 1):

For $y=4 \cdot \cos(5x)-3 \cdot \sin(2x)$.

$y'=4 \cdot (\cos(5x))' + \cos(5x) \cdot (4)'-(3 \cdot (\sin(2x))'+\sin(2x) \cdot (3)')=4 \cdot (-5) \cdot \sin(5x) - 3 \cdot 2 \cdot \cos(2x)=-20 \cdot \sin(5x)-6 \cdot \cos(2x)$.